# Sync audio in video via ffmpeg?

Tags: unix, audio, ffmpeg

I need to fit audio with video, but sync option is negative (audio is -350 ms) How to fit it with video? I see only examples when audio is +, but not -

Comment: StackOverflow is dedicated to helping solve programming code problems. Your Q **may be**  more appropriate for [su]  , but read their help section regarding on-topic questions . AND please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) and [Help How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/How-to-ask) before posting more Qs here.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

ffmpeg -i "sample.mp4" -itsoffset 13.84 -i "sample.mp4" -map 1:v -map 0:a -c copy "movie-video-delayed.mp4"